# Merge sort program doesn't sort array with more than 5 elements

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to implement the code for merge sort. I use the following code for merge sort, which you can have a look at [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort/tutorial/). The problem is when I run the program, for example, I asked it to sort the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5] then print out the sorted array, it return the array [-1560047667 1 2 3 4 5]. From what I observed, it will not print the value of the largest element in the array correctly. My code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int A[], int start, int end){
    My code for merge sort 
    goes here
}

int main(){
    int n, i, *A;
    A = (int *)malloc(n);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) scanf("%d", A+i);
    merge_sort(A, 0, n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d", *(A+i));
}
```

Any suggestion on what is the mistake I've made? I think the problem is at the input/output process, but not quite sure what exactly it is.

Comment: Instead of `A = (int *)malloc(n);`, try `A = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`.

Comment: first scan `n`, then use it for malloc

Comment: Did you try your program on shorter arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to develop psychic powers. You're using `n` before it gets assigned a value as you use `scanf` afterwards to find out what `n` should be. This will lead to undefined behaviour, such as your code only working if there are less than 5 elements.

```
int n, i, *A;
A = (int *)malloc(n);
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You're also not allocating enough memory as that will allocate `n` bytes where as an `int` will typically be 4 bytes (or more or less depending on your computer's architecture). The best way to ensure you allocate the right amount of memory is to multiple `n` by the `sizeof(*A)` - that is the size of whatever A is a pointer to. This ensures if you change `A` to be a different type, the allocation code will continue to be correct.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
A = malloc(n*sizeof(*A));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, I've been wondering why we use malloc instead of scan n and then we initiate an array a[n]. At first I thought that malloc allows that kind of "psychic" power that you are talking about but now it seems unlikely. Would you mind explaining this?

Comment: Arrays are using up space in the stack which is limited, where as `malloc` allocates memory from the heap which isn't as limited and you can also `free` it when you no longer need it.

Comment: @MS1902, do note that support for arrays whose sizes are not compile-time constants ("variable-length arrays") is mixed.  It was not a feature of C90 at all, it was added to C99, but then support was made optional in C11.  Some compilers support it, but others don't.  Also it is prone to fail for much smaller array dimensions than are usually required to make `malloc()` fail.  Bottom line: be careful with VLAs, and maybe don't use them at all until you know what you're doing.